Reported speech modal verbs
"You needn't come tomorrow"
He said she neeedn't  or wouldn't have to  come the next day"
In other words. Do we have to  change "needn't" in reported speech or we can leave it in the same form?

The BBC offers this answer, which turned up from a very easy Google search.

@PaulTanenbaumm I'm not lazy. Many sites say different things and teachers do the same. Thanks

For instance my teacher told to me change that. You say that I don't havr to. Confusing haha

I wasn’t suggesting you were lazy. The indications of what one has tried, what resulted from it, and why that didn’t suffice don’t only offer evidence that people aren’t asking others to do their work for them. They also help people better understand one’s question so they can provide more useful and better aimed answers.

"He said she didn't have to..." or "...didn't need to come the next day".
